# p:calendar value not updated with dateSelect

Tags: primefaces, calendar

I have got a p:calendar component inside a p:dialog one. When dialog is shown it takes its value from property in back bean, but when a new date is selected, the SelectEvent arrived to the listener brings the old value and not the new selected date. What is wrong on next code?

```
   <p:dialog id="eventDialog" widgetVar="eventDialog" header="#{textos.confirmarFechaHora}" showEffect="clip" 
         hideEffect="clip" modal="true"
         appendToBody="true"> <!-- A false, no entran los eventos tras modificar la fecha/hora del calendario --> 
  <h:panelGrid id="eventDetails" columns="2">  
     <h:outputLabel for="calHora" value="#{textos.horaComienzo}" />  
     <p:calendar id="calHora" locale="es" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" 
                 value="#{schedulePFController.fechaComienzo}" mode="inline"
                 required="true"
                 accesskey="true" valueChangeListener="#{schedulePFController.cambiaHoraComienzoVCL}">
        <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{schedulePFController.cambiaHoraComienzo}"/>
     </p:calendar>
     <p:commandButton value="#{textos.cancelar}" oncomplete="eventDialog.hide();"/>  
     <p:commandButton value="#{textos.mostrarCitas}" 
                      action="#{schedulePFController.verEntradaCalendario}" 
                      rendered="#{schedulePFController.clickedOnCita}"/>
     <p:commandButton value="#{textos.addCita}" 
                      action="#{schedulePFController.addCita}" 
                      rendered="#{!schedulePFController.clickedOnCita}"/>
  </h:panelGrid>
```

```
public void cambiaHoraComienzo(SelectEvent ev) {
  Date date = (Date)ev.getObject();
  fechaComienzo = date;
  horaComienzo = new DateCita(date);
  logger.debug("Cambiando fechaComienzo "+horaComienzo.toString()+" +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");}
```

Comment: have you initialized `SchedulePFController` attribute `fechaComienzo` with any default value?

Comment: oh I just see `valueChangeListener="#{schedulePFController.cambiaHoraComienzoVCL}"` here you are calling another method and you are looking value in `cambiaHoraComienzo` method? What are you doing man?

Comment: Remove `valueChangeListener="#{schedulePFController.cambiaHoraComienzoVCL}"` from your `p:calender` and then check.listener `listener="#{schedulePFController.cambiaHoraComienzo}"` that you are using in `p:ajax` tag is enough

Comment: This seems to be a problem with older versions of PrimeFaces. This has been fixed in PrimeFaces 3.3 or 3.3.1. Try to upgrade to a newer version.

Comment: I have the same problem and I can't upgrade a big project...

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you are using `valueChangeListener="#{schedulePFController.cambiaHoraComienzoVCL}"` in `p:calender` when you are already invoking a listner in your ajax call.
Just remove `valueChangeListener="#{schedulePFController.cambiaHoraComienzoVCL}"` from your `p:calender` and then check.listener `listener="#{schedulePFController.cambiaHoraComienzo}"` that you are using in `p:ajax` tag is enough

Comment: Thank you for your help. valueChangeListener is not being called. I have tried with and without it. The only listener called is the listener of p:ajax event dateSelect, but the event arriving has not the new date selected

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this the wrong way, to complicated.

Take a look here:

```
        <p:calendar value="#{ivkDaten.beginn}" locale="de" lang="de"
            pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" label="#{messages['services.ivk.beginn']}:" 
            width="80" id="ivkbeginn" effect="fadeIn" readonlyInput="true" disabled="true"
            showOn="button" mindate="#{services.minDate}" maxdate="#{services.maxDate}">

            <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{ivkDaten.recalcDate()}"
                update="ablauf" />
        </p:calendar>
```

You need to set getter/setter for `beginn` and when you call  the method `"reclacDate()"` you can use `beginn` and i'm pretty sure you will have the new date.

Comment: Yes, I have initialized fechaComienzo and then this is the value that will come with the SelectEvent, even if I have selected another date

Comment: You don't even need to use SelectEvent. just call your method `public void cambiaHoraComienzo() { ... }` . just use `<p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{schedulePFController.cambiaHoraComienzo()}" />` like this.

Comment: When recalcDate is called, beginn is not updated with the new date

Comment: It should, if you did everything right. What scope do you use?

Comment: Session scope for bean schedulePFController

Comment: Did you remove `valueChangeListener` from `p:calendar`? Do you use getter/setter? Did you implement `Serializable` in your bean?

Comment: yes to all, it could be due to be p:calendar included inside p:dialog?

Comment: No, I use the same in a dialog, it does not have to do anyhting with dialog

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be a problem with older versions of PrimeFaces. This has been fixed in PrimeFaces 3.3 or 3.3.1. Try to upgrade to a newer version.

Answer (score -1):

This `p:calendar` is inside a `h:form`?

We had the exact same problem and noted that we had forget this