# p:calendar value not set in backing bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces, calendar

Hi I am using PrimeFaces. I have a `<p:calendar>` in a dialog box and I would type date manual . But my date is not setting in bean's variable. It works for dataSelect event but don't work keypress or keydown event. I am wondering it is also working outside dialog box. Here is my code:

```jsf
<p:calendar readonlyInput="false" id="Date1" rendered="true"
    navigator="true" showButtonPanel="true"  
    styleClass="form-control cal_input" showOn="both" 
    pattern="#{sessionManager.defaultDateFormat.substring(0,11)}"
    yearRange="#{appLabel['year_Range']}" tabindex="203" 
    value="#{mangeCreateOrdersTO.searchOrderPatientBean.DOB}"
    disabled="false" mask="true"
    maxdate="#{mangeCreateOrdersTO.maxDateOfBirth}"
    autocomplete="#{appLabel['autoCompleteSetting']}"
    onkeypress="return disableEnterKey(event)">
  <p:ajax event="dateSelect" process="@this" partialSubmit="true"  ignoreAutoUpdate="true" update="form:Date1"/>
  <p:ajax event="keydown" process="@this" immediate="true" partialSubmit="true" ignoreAutoUpdate="true" listener="#{mangeCreateOrdersTO.add(mangeCreateOrdersTO.searchOrderPatientBean.DOB)}"/>
</p:calendar>
```

Please help me to get rid from this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [ask] and [mcve] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: tried the blur event? change event?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16437986/pcalendar-value-not-updated-with-dateselect?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong. So:

My `<p:Calendar>` must be under the `<h:form>` which I was missing.