# Primefaces calendar does not set the date

Tags: jsf, primefaces, calendar

I have yet another misunderstanding of Primefaces work logic.

For now `<p:calendar>` component cannot set selected date when I press submit button.
I see that it successfully enters into actionListener method, but date value is null there.

First of all I tried create my calendar using standard PF [example](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/calendar.xhtml). It looked too simple and I thought according this that the component should call value setter when the user select the date or submit the form. But it did it neither in the first nor in the second case.
Well, I opened Google and found a few posts:

[Primefaces Calendar Setting Date Value in Backing Bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737414/primefaces-calendar-setting-date-value-in-backing-bean)
[p:calendar value not set in backing bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35892935/pcalendar-value-not-set-in-backing-bean)

I ensured that my calendar is located between `<h:form></h:form>` tags. Also I tried to add `process="@this"` and `process=":beginDateForm :endDateForm @this"`, where beginDateForm and endDateForm are forms contained `<p:calendar>` components.
Also I found the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16437986/pcalendar-value-not-updated-with-dateselect) and tried to create SelectEvent listener method:

```
private void changeDate(SelectEvent event) {
    beginDate = (Date) event.getObject();
}
```

But unsuccessfully.

I also tried to change Date using valueChangeListener:

```
<h:form id="beginDateForm">
    <p:calendar id="passBeginDate" valueChangeListener="#{territoryFormBean.changeDate}" mode="popup" readonly="true" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" showOn="button" value="#{territoryFormBean.beginDate}" />
</h:form>
```

Of course I changed event to ValueChangeEvent.

After that I moved `<p:calendar>` and `<p:commandButton>` components into the same `<h:form>` and tried two different process values `process="passTerrForm:passBeginDate passTerrForm:passEndDate @this"` and `process="@form @this"` and `process="@form"`
In the last case button does not trigger even the listener method.

My current components are:

```
<p:commandButton value="Search" id="searchPassButton" actionListener="#{territoryFormBean.search}" update=":passTerrForm:territoryTable" process="passTerrForm:passBeginDate passTerrForm:passEndDate @this" partialSubmit="true" />

<p:column>
    <p:calendar id="passBeginDate" mode="popup" readonly="true" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" showOn="button" value="#{territoryFormBean.beginDate}" />
</p:column>
<p:column>
    <p:calendar id="passEndDate" mode="popup" readonly="true" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" showOn="button" value="#{territoryFormBean.endDate}" />
</p:column>
```

Guys, could you please suggest anything else. Or probably you can see what is wrong in my code.
I cannot understand why the component does not call setter.

Comment: The code throws some error ?

Comment: @PolRodríguez no. It does not. I checked NetBeans output and found only Fine and Finest messages with something like 'component created'

Comment: By the way, I also checked that input fields which are located in the same page are submited correctly. I can see in debug mode that java fields have correct values.

Comment: What's the scope of `territoryFormBean`?

Comment: @XtremeBiker, initially the bean is ViewScoped. I tried to change it to SessionScoped, but unsuccessfully

Comment: I continue to investigate the issue.
As I can see the element `<p:calendar>` generate the following structure:
`<span id="passTerrForm:terrBeginDate">` with id which I set in the for `<p:calendar>`.
And span tag includes `<input id="passTerrForm:terrBeginDate_input" type="text">` and `<button type="button">` tags.
I tried put `passTerrForm:terrBeginDate_input` id to process parameter of submit button. But no success. I just received exception that `passTerrForm:terrBeginDate_input` id not found.
Well, can anybody explain how exactly the system reads the value from `<p:calendar>`?

Answer (score 4):

Well, guys, I found my mistake. Stupid mistake. Yet another re-read the PF documentation showed that using `readonly` parameter is incorrect for my goals. I wanted to prevent the manual date input directly into `<p:calendar>` text field. But according the documentation: 
`readonly` -

> Flag indicating that this input element will prevent changes by the
>   user

But I need `readonlyInput` parameter which

> Makes input text of a popup calendar readonly.

So the second parameter prevents input, while the first one prevents changes totally.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to make an analogy with a code that I have, I think that putting the button into the same form as the calendar, and omitting the 'process' and 'partialSubmit' should work:

```
    <h:form id="beginDateForm">
     <p:calendar id="passBeginDate" valueChangeListener="#{territoryFormBean.changeDate}" mode="popup" readonly="true" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" showOn="button" value="#{territoryFormBean.beginDate}" />
     <p:commandButton value="Search" id="searchPassButton" actionListener="#{territoryFormBean.search}" update=":passTerrForm:territoryTable" />
    </h:form>
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your respond. I tried to do it but unfortunately it did not help. 
All inputText fields and select menus passes values, but calendars are not :(

Comment: You should ommit the valueChangeListener too in the code above, I skipped that detail in my response.

Comment: Well, for now I removed valueChangeListener and returned to initial tutorial configuration. But I cannot remove 'process' parameter. Otherwise form does not pass even inputText fields values into managed bean.

Answer (score 0):

JSF Code:

```
<p:calendar id="from" value="#{pageBean.event.startDate}"   pattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a" timeZone="GMT-4"/>

<p:commandButton id="addButton" value="Save" actionListener="#{pageBean.addEvent}" update=":@form"/>
```

You can write an **addEvent** method in the Bean where you need to add these calendar event to an **eventModel** and save it. This helps you to set the date and you can retrieve it as and when you need.

Java Code:

```
private ScheduleModel eventModel;
private ScheduleEvent event = new DefaultScheduleEvent();
public String addEvent(ActionEvent actionEvent) {    

   if(event.getId() == null){
        eventModel.addEvent(event);
   }
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I still cannot understand event model concept, I will investigate it. But it really looks strange. As I can see in PF tutorial the date can be simply passed via the value parameter which has Date type in java backend.

Comment: Did you get the save for the calendar events working?

Comment: It is not necessary for me now to process calendar events manually. For my goals it's enough just choose date and pass it to the managed bean via the submit button. As I already wrote I found the mistake and could use the default way to set date.